# Use selection from previous mysql-statement

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

Basically I'm writing a bash script that is supposed to select multiple values from 2 mysql tables.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h "mydomain.de" "database1" << EOF
SET @user='testuser';
SELECT serverId FROM member WHERE username = @user;
SELECT slots FROM server WHERE id = @serverId;
EOF
```

I set the variable for @user for testing purposes, normally it's given by a php script.

I just don't know how to use the result I get from the first SELECT statement ( the serverId ) to be used in the second SELECT statement in order to find out the slots this server contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you could just do it in one SQL SELECT:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="testuser"
slots=$(mysql -uuser -ppassword -Ddatabase -N -e "SELECT slots FROM server,member WHERE server.id=member.serverId AND member.username='$user';")
```

You might want to play with bash arrays to parse results.

If that's true you can make multiple mysql-client calls to do that, keep in mind it's always better to make your DBMS perform the joining/sorting/formatting instead of your own code.

Comment: thank you for that, but now it's printing the following error:

ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'testuser' in 'where clause'

Comment: alright nvm. i had to put testuser into single quotes like so:

user='"testuser"'.

now its working, thank you very much!